# ¿Como hago para duplicar un Sprite + su codigo 2 veces y hacer que sus random speed sean diferentes en Godot?

Tags: random, godot-engine

Básicamente estoy creado un pez y haciendo que nade de derecha a izquierda, luego en cierto punto retrocederá a la derecha simulando que sea otro pez. Mi problema es que dupliqué el mismo pez pero este me da el mismo random speed que el anterior y parece que siempre da los mismos random values, pero lo que quiero es que al duplicarlos me de diferentes valores, por ejemplo en C++ ponía srand (time(NULL)) y no me repetía los randoms. Básicamente la pregunta es como duplicar el mismo sprite de pez y hacer que no se repitan los valores randoms, como que cada duplicado corra a una velocidad diferente. Algo diferente a cambiar el nombre de las variables.
Este es el código principal:

```
extends Sprite

var is_moving = false
var rand = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
var speed = rand.randf_range(500,100)
var velocity = Vector2.LEFT * speed

#Here we are saying, if buttom is pressed (something happend)
func _on_Button_pressed():
    #Changue a variable to true is what happends when u press the buttom
    is_moving = !is_moving

#_procces will always been running, but here nothing happends, until the buttom
#make true is_moving
func _process(delta):

    #Action-------------------------------
    if Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_K):
        _on_Button_pressed()

    if is_moving:
        position += velocity * delta

        if position.x <= 100:
            position.x = 1000
            speed = rand.randf_range(500,100)
            velocity = Vector2.LEFT * speed
    #--------------------------------------
```

Y esta es una idea de la carrera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné con un randi, ahora el codigo se ve así:

```
extends Sprite

var is_moving = false
var speed = 300 + randi() % 201
var velocity = Vector2.LEFT * speed

#Here we are saying, if buttom is pressed (something happend)
func _on_Button_pressed():
    #Changue a variable to true is what happends when u press the buttom
    is_moving = !is_moving

#_procces will always been running, but here nothing happends, until the buttom
#make true is_moving
func _process(delta):
    
    #Action-------------------------------
    if Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_K):
        _on_Button_pressed()

    if is_moving:
        position += velocity * delta

        if position.x <= 100:
            print(speed)
            position.x = 1000
            speed = 300 + (randi() % 201)
            velocity = Vector2.LEFT * speed
    #--------------------------------------
```